# Which font should I use when I'm writing?

Tags: style

I know most people want to see courier, well, at least that is what I think (correct me if I'm wrong.)

I would probably never be able to finish a novel or any kind of book for that matter (not skilled enough to try) and my current platform is largely web based. In the world of the online writer, which font would you recommend? The courier font looks a bit, how can I put it, bland?

Before I ramble on into infinity my question boils down to this, which font and sizes should I use when writing with the intent to publish online?

Any input would be highly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to ever finish writing anything, stop seeking excuses not to write, like "I don't know what font to choose". You can always change the font globally *after* you wrote your book.

Comment: If your question is "What font should I use when posting on the web?" then it's not a writing question. It's a graphic design or web design question.

Comment: If you're just looking for a standard, Times 12 pt or Calibri 11 pt are the most common in my experience.

Comment: @James The most common fonts on websites today are sans-serif (Arial). Serif fonts (Times) are rarely used for body text. (For example, writer.stackexchange uses Helvetica, a sans-serif font.)

Comment: I'm partial to linotype

Comment: Closing, as per votes and @LaurenIpsum 's comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you publish online, you have two basic options:

(1) Do not specify a font. Your text will appear in the user's default web font. This is actually a good option. Many websites do just that. Those fonts are easy to read and unobtrusive in the best way.

(2) Use one of the web fonts that all computers today have installed. The most common fonts on websites are Arial and Verdana.

All of these fonts, both in option one and two, are specifically designed to be easy to read on a computer screen. Print fonts often are a bit blurry and merge in the details, making them less attractive on a screen.

There are more fonts for option two, and a third option (defining different fonts for different operating systems) and a fourth (including fonts in your document or including it from an online resource), and if you want you can learn about fonts on the web, which is a vast field and can be pretty complicated, but the above options are perfectly fine and standard and will serve you well without much effort on your part.

Answer (score 2):

As I read the question, I think you mean what font you should use *while* writing (as opposed to *after* finishing writing)?

**Crimson Text** is gorgeous. I'll make you finish your manuscript even if the story is absolute crap:

[image]

Comment: I prefer Souvenir Light from ITC. It is perfectly balanced and has a friendly, unassuming feel to it. Always makes me smile to read or write in it.

Comment: @what Nice. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

When I write the book, I pick a font that I find visually pleasing, personally.  It can always be changed later before being sent to a publisher.  It is best to actually work on it when you like what you are looking at.  My current favorite is Calibri (body).

Answer (score 0):

The best fonts to use are the ones that are common and easy to read are Calibri (body). No bold, italics, or any other font effects used.  Writers choose particular font because it looks good and shows proper standard of writing.